# Socket blocked on Google App Engine Standard Java8

Tags: google-app-engine

[This documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sockets/) says that:

> Applications in the Java 8 runtime can use native Java sockets with no restrictions

However a socket to port 25 get blocked somewhere. The code bellow works fine on my local JVM but not in Google app engine Java8 standard env.

```
Socket skt = new Socket("gmail.com", 25);
BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
```

I have been going through the docs for days now, but cannot find anything explaining why its not working. Nothing on my logs neither.

Can I open a socket to port 25 on GAE or not? please help

Comment: The quoted note *might* be misleading, possibly referring to just the java-specific limitations. But some of the limitations mentioned on that page, at least those for ports (including port 25)  are most likely a matter of policy, not language support-related - they appear for other languages as well, not only for Java7 - check all the other language tabs right below the table of content at the top of the page. I suspect those *might* not fall in the scope of the quoted note.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I agree with your analysis. I wonder if there is any chance of getting an official Google answer on this forum or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 25 is always blocked for [mail related security reasons](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).

In the [Java sockets documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sockets/) that you shared is stated that:

> Port 25 (SMTP) is blocked; you can still use authenticated SMTP on the submission port 587.

It's true that the documentation is somewhat misleading about if this port limitation applies only to Java 7 runtime or affects Java 8 too. I'll send feedback about this documentation page to prevent future confusion.